# Why is the memory in GPU still in use after clearing the object?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, gpu, pytorch

Starting with zero usage:

```
>>> import gc
>>> import GPUtil
>>> import torch
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% |  0% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

Then I create a big enough tensor and hog the memory:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(10000,300,200).cuda()
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% | 26% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

Then I tried several ways to see if the tensor disappears.

**Attempt 1:** Detach, send to CPU and overwrite the variable

**No, doesn't work.**

```
>>> x = x.detach().cpu()
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% | 26% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

**Attempt 2:** Delete the variable

**No, this doesn't work either**

```
>>> del x
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% | 26% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

**Attempt 3:** Use the `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` function

Seems to work, but it seems that there are some lingering overheads...

```
>>> torch.cuda.empty_cache()
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% |  5% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

**Attempt 4:** Maybe clear the garbage collector.

**No, 5% is still being hogged**

```
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% |  5% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

**Attempt 5:** Try deleting `torch` altogether (as if that would work when `del x` didn't work -_- )

**No, it doesn't...***

```
>>> del torch
>>> GPUtil.showUtilization()
| ID | GPU | MEM |
------------------
|  0 |  0% |  5% |
|  1 |  0% |  0% |
|  2 |  0% |  0% |
|  3 |  0% |  0% |
```

And then I tried to check `gc.get_objects()` and it looks like there's still quite a lot of odd `THCTensor` stuff inside...

**Any idea why is the memory still in use after clearing the cache?**

Comment: First, confirm which process is using the GPU memory using `nvidia-smi`. There the process id `pid` can be used to find the process. If no processes are shown but GPU memory is still being used, you can try [this method](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/958159/cuda-programming-and-performance/11-gb-of-gpu-ram-used-and-no-process-listed-by-nvidia-smi/) to clear the memory.

Comment: gc.collect() before torch.cuda.remove_cache() resolved this issue on my end.

Answer (score 18):

It looks like PyTorch's caching allocator reserves some fixed amount of memory even if there are no tensors, and this allocation is triggered by the first CUDA memory access
(`torch.cuda.empty_cache()` deletes unused tensor from the cache, but the cache itself still uses some memory).

Even with a tiny 1-element tensor, after `del` and `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`, `GPUtil.showUtilization(all=True)` reports exactly the same amount of GPU memory used as for a huge tensor (and both `torch.cuda.memory_cached()` and `torch.cuda.memory_allocated()` return zero).

Answer (score 16):

From the [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#memory-management):

> #### Memory management
>
> PyTorch uses a caching memory allocator to speed up memory
> allocations. This allows fast memory deallocation without device
> synchronizations. However, **the unused memory managed by the allocator
> will still show as if used in nvidia-smi**. You can use
> `memory_allocated()` and `max_memory_allocated()` to monitor memory
> occupied by tensors, and use `memory_cached()` and `max_memory_cached()`
> to monitor memory managed by the caching allocator. Calling
> `empty_cache()` releases all unused cached memory from PyTorch so that
> those can be used by other GPU applications. However, the occupied GPU
> memory by tensors will not be freed so it can not increase the amount
> of GPU memory available for PyTorch.

I bolded a part mentioning **nvidia-smi**, which as far as I know is used by GPUtil.

Comment: Torch might also allocate memory for things like an internal system / manager. Probably its allocator.

Comment: What about the sentence about `empty_cache()`? For me it clearly sounds like it really frees memory, that is it is free also in a "nvidia-smi-free" way.

Comment: Indeed, but unfortunately it is also stated that it frees only memory considered by pytorch as unused... This might be this lingering 5%.

Comment: Yes. There must be something internal as @Tiphaine suggested too. But these 5% of OP are about half a Gigabyte! And then again the doc only knows "unused cache memory" and "occupied GPU memory by tensors" which these 5% seem to neither belong to.

Comment: Also note that cuda and torch allocate some memory for kernels, so even if you make a very tiny tensor on gpu, it can still take up to 1.5GB GPU memory: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12873#issuecomment-482916237 This memory is not considered as allocated or reserved by pytorch's allocator

Comment: `memory_cached()` and `max_memory_cached()` are now called `memory_reserved()`  and `max_memory_reserved()`.

Answer (score 9):

thanks for sharing this! I am running in the same problem and I used your example to debug. Basically, my findings are:

- collect() and empty_cache() only work after deleting variables
- **del var + empty_cache()** free cached **and** allocated memory
- **del var + collect()** free only allocated memory
- either way, there's still some overhead memory usage visible from nvidia-smi

Here's some code to reproduce the experiment:

```
    
import gc
import torch

def _get_less_used_gpu():
    from torch import cuda
    cur_allocated_mem = {}
    cur_cached_mem = {}
    max_allocated_mem = {}
    max_cached_mem = {}
    for i in range(cuda.device_count()):
        cur_allocated_mem[i] = cuda.memory_allocated(i)
        cur_cached_mem[i] = cuda.memory_reserved(i)
        max_allocated_mem[i] = cuda.max_memory_allocated(i)
        max_cached_mem[i] = cuda.max_memory_reserved(i)
    print(cur_allocated_mem)
    print(cur_cached_mem)
    print(max_allocated_mem)
    print(max_cached_mem)
    min_all = min(cur_allocated_mem, key=cur_allocated_mem.get)
    print(min_all)
    return min_all

x = torch.rand(10000,300,200, device=0)

# see memory usage
_get_less_used_gpu()
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
> *nvidia-smi*: 3416MiB

# try delete with empty_cache()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
_get_less_used_gpu()
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
> *nvidia-smi*: 3416MiB

# try delete with gc.collect()
gc.collect()
_get_less_used_gpu()
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
> *nvidia-smi*: 3416MiB

# try del + gc.collect()
del x 
gc.collect()
_get_less_used_gpu()
>{0: **0**, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
> *nvidia-smi*: 3416MiB

# try empty_cache() after deleting 
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
_get_less_used_gpu()
>{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: **0**, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
> *nvidia-smi*: **1126MiB**

# re-create obj and try del + empty_cache()
x = torch.rand(10000,300,200, device=0)
del x
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
_get_less_used_gpu()
>{0: **0**, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: **0**, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2400000000, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
>{0: 2401239040, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}
> *nvidia-smi*: **1126MiB**
```

Nonetheless, this approach only applies when one knows exactly which variables are holding memory...which is not always the case when one trains deep learning modes I guess, especially when using third-party libraries.