# I have been using colab for a DL framework for NeRF. but it keeps telling that the GPU memory is exceeded

Tags: memory, gpu, google-colaboratory, torch

This the code that I used. Here, the device is cuda. I tried to move up and down the GPU. When I push it to the GPU, memory keeps increasing, but when I get it off GPU, the memory is not freed. I use Colab for this.

```
    if self.useViewDirs:
        for chunk_pos, chunk_view in zip(chunks_pos, chunks_view):
            # res = self.coarse_model(torch.cat((chunk_pos, chunk_view), dim = -1))
            chunk_pos_GPU, chunk_view_GPU = chunk_pos.to(device), chunk_view.to(device)
            self.coarse_model.to(device)
            res_GPU = self.coarse_model(chunk_pos_GPU, chunk_view_GPU)
            res = res_GPU.to('cpu')
            del res_GPU, chunk_pos_GPU, chunk_view_GPU
            self.coarse_model.to('cpu')
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

            predictions.append(res)
    # predictions: (H * W * N_samples/chunksize, chunksize, 3:(RGB color) + 1:(color))
    else:
        pass
```

I think the code should work, but it does not.

Comment: I think this thread explains the reason and solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496285/why-is-the-memory-in-gpu-still-in-use-after-clearing-the-object